# How to get combinations of an array with condition that there are at-least 4 of each type of element (or x of each type)?

Tags: python, combinations

I am trying to write a python function to get all combinations of length n of an input array where there are at-least 4 (or certain # x ) of each type of specific element (example below)

```
input = ['m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','w1','w2','w3','w4','w5','w6']
```

output = list of combinations where there are atleast 4 of every type of element (i.e. 4 for each day of the week IF those elements are present at all (if 0, doesnt matter))

for combination in itertools.combinations(input_array, 12):

For example from the input array, a valid output for n=12 would below

```
out = ['m1','m2','m3','m4,','t3','t4,'t5','t6','w1','w2','w3','w4']
```

while an invalid output that it generates would be

```
out = ['m1','m2','m3','t2','t3','t4,'t5','t6','w1','w2','w3','w4']
```

Is there a more efficient way of generating combinations where there are atleast 4 of every type (i.e. 4 entries with 'm', 4 entries with 't', 4 entries with 'w'). Right now I simply loop through all combinations as 
it comes and if it passes that check I put it into an array, but with larger input arrays this can take a very long time. If there is another method other than combinations that would also work.

Edit to clarify additional needs, I realize I did not provide some critical information.

Any input array can have up to seven different types of elements. This makes I more complicated because when i only need 12 elements (at-least 4 of each type **if present**), and additionally **order must be preserved** in reference to the original input array for each element type (**this is a bonus, if it cannot be done that is oka**y).

Examples
Input can be = [m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,t1,t2,t3,t4,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3,f4].

**Valid output:**

[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12] (can be all of one type since others not present)

[m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,t1,t2,t3,t4] (or atleast 4 of each type in order)

[m4,m5,m6,m7,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3,f4] (atleast 4 of each type **if present**, but can be missing)
etc.

**Not valid:**

[m4,m6,m5,m7,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3,f4] (out of order)

[m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3] (not 4 of each type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
import re, collections
data = ['m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','w1','w2','w3','w4','w5','w6']
def combo(d, c = []):
  if len(c) == 12:
     yield c
  else:
     for i in d:
        _count1 = collections.Counter([re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', j)[0] for j in c])
        _count2 = collections.Counter([re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', j)[0] for j in c+[i]])
        if i not in c:
           if len(c) < 11 or all(b >= 4 for b in _count2.values()):
              if re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', i)[0] in _count1:
                 if int(re.findall('\d+$', i)[0])-1 == int(re.findall('\d+$', c[-1])[0]) and re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', i)[0] == re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', c[-1])[0]:
                    yield from combo(d, c+[i])
              else:
                 yield from combo(d, c+[i])

result = combo(data)
for _ in range(10): #first 10 results from generator
  print(next(result))
```

Output:

```
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']
['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5']
```

---

Edit: filtering out similar results:

```
r, result = [], combo(data)
for _ in range(40):
   r.append(next(result))

new_r = [a for i, a in enumerate(r) if all(sorted(a) != sorted(k) for k in r[:i])]
print(f'{len(r)} => {len(new_r)}')
```

Output:

```
40 => 22
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer. Can you take a look at my edit, I made some clarifications for my needs (im really not sure if what I am asking for is possible)

Comment: @user3794422 No problem, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Wow this is great. This pretty much solves it, I was just wondeeing, is there any way to enforce it so elements of the same type are still sequential? For example, it your third output example it shows w1,w2,w3,w5 which I would want to exclude but w2,w3,w4,w5 (or more than 4 but still sequential?) Is okay. However, thank you for this answer.

Comment: @user3794422 Please see my recent edit, I updated the solution to reflect this

Comment: @user3794422 Glad to help!

Comment: Hello, I had one last question (if you don't mind, otherwise I can post a new question). Is there a way to make it so that it prints only unique arrays where arrays with the same elements (even if ordered differently) are treated as the same? For example, an array with m1,m2,m3,m4,t1,t2,t3,t4 is same as
 t1,t2,t3,t4,m1,m2,m3,m4, etc (for 12 elements, just used this as example).

Comment: @user3794422 No problem, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Thank ! This solves everything for me, really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3794422 No problem, glad to help!

Comment: Hello again. I wanted to ask, since I have been using your function which works perfectly, if you had an idea of how I should pre-process this input ['f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7', 't8', 't9', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7', 'r8', 'r9', 'm0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3']. This input works, but it takes a long time to find the first valid output using your function. Sorry for bothering you so many times on this problem!

Comment: @user3794422 No problem at all. Can you clarify what you mean by "pre-processing" in the context of this problem? Unfortunately, this type of computation is indeed very complex and often does take a while to solve. See the [Knapsack_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: Ah i see. I apologize, I am a relative newbie when it comes to programming. I was just wondering if there was any way to potentially speed up finding a correct answer by changing the input array, but I realize that might not really be plausible. Thanks for all your help. I can make do by letting it run as long as it needs to.

Comment: @user3794422 No problem at all. There are certainly ways of increasing the speed within a certain input size range, however, that is outside my realm of knowledge. I suggest you post again with the code above and ask for specific help regarding optimization. I, too, would like to know about the different possibilities!

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I really do appreciate it. I went ahead and asked the question, maybe someone can help me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first split your data into different types:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']
c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

then, you can generate all possible combinations of each seed:

```
comb_a = combinations(a, 3)  
comb_b = combinations(b, 4) 
comb_c = combinations(c, 2) 
for i, j, k in zip(list(comb_a), list(comb_b), list(comb_c)):
    print(i+j+k)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer. Can you take a look at my edit, I made some clarifications for my needs (im really not sure if what I am asking for is possible). I won't always know how much of each type I need (since it can be 0, 4, or any number greater than 4). That limits how I can use your approach I believe.